# Bootstrap 4 Navbar, Button Group right, dropdown menu not vertical

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

This is a weird frustrating issue, as I'm working on converting code from Bootstrap 3 to 4. Navbar with a button group on the right (user name, login options, etc.)

When the button group is not a part of the navbar (not included in the menu -- I have PHP code that is not shown below that checks for a specific page if the menu (navbar) is to be displayed or not, the dropdown list appears correct -- vertical, etc. If, however, I place the button group in the navbar, the dropdown list goes horizontal.

I am sure this is because some of the code is somehow interfering with other parts, but I cannot figure it out. Stripping out the PHP code, and just showing the HTML for Bootstrap 4, this is what I have -- first with button group without the navbar:

```
  <nav class="nav navbar-light bg-light navbar-right" style="margin-top: 3px !important;">
     <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">hirsch</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="width: 200px;">
           <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Change Password</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Manage User ID</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Logout</a>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div> <!-- / dropdown-menu -->
     </div> <!-- / btn-group -->
  </nav>  <!-- / navbar-right -->
```

That code displays as expected. If, however, I insert this before the end of the collapse part of the navbar (or if I put it after, it doesn't seem to matter), it displays horizontally instead, which is ... weird:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a>
                 </li>

                 <li class="nav-item" >
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Who's Who</a>
                 </li>

                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Disclaimer/Copyright</a>
                 </li>

                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact Us</a>
                 </li>

              </ul> <!-- / navbar-nav -->

<nav class="nav navbar-light bg-light navbar-right" style="margin-top: 3px !important;">
     <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">UserName</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="width: 200px;">
           <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Change Password</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Manage User ID</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Logout</a>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div> <!-- / dropdown-menu -->
     </div> <!-- / btn-group -->
  </nav>  <!-- / navbar-right --> 

 </div> <!-- / collapse -->
</nav>
```

You should be able to copy and paste the code samples and see them if you have the rest of Bootstrap 4 set up. Click the down-caret symbol on the button group, in the first example it is vertical, in the second it is horizontal, but it's the exact same code. I am really confused where the issue is, I've been staring at this for quite some time and cannot find the problem.

Comment: What stylesheets are you importing?

Comment: I'm using the one from Bootstrap, and a personal one, but that one doesn't have any classes that are affecting this that I can see.

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous" />

My personal one deals with nav-tabs, but not nav-bars, nav-items or nav-links, dropdown-menus, etc. (and will need to be revised for nav-tabs, I'm sure).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the Dropdown has changed a bit, and rather than using a UL tag and such:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Change Password</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Manage User ID</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Logout</a>
          </li>
</ul>
```

It works better (and simpler) with:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="width: 200px;"> 
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Change Password</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Manage User ID</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Logout</a>
</div>
```